# How to add thousand separator in react native

Tags: react-native

- I have used `balance.toLocalString` but it's not working in Android
- balance.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","); not working proper in android(also formating decimal values like 12.2364 to 12.2,364)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this, I have found two solutions

- Fixed the decimal value
  `return balance.toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");`
- Spit the balance and after formatting rejoin the balance

`

```
function thousandFormatter(number) {
const THOUSAND_FORMATTER = new RegExp(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g);
     if (!Boolean(number)) {
         return;
     }
     const numberSplitter = ".";
     if (number.includes(numberSplitter)) {
         const numberToFormat = number.split(numberSplitter);
         return [numberToFormat[0].replace(THOUSAND_FORMATTER, ","), numberToFormat[1]]
             .join(numberSplitter)
             .trim();
     }
     return number.replace(THOUSAND_FORMATTER, ",");
 }
```